# Como convertir de byte [] a string en LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Estoy intentando de convertir de byte [] a string pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetString(Byte[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

```
return (from c in db.Zapato select new { c.IDZapato, c.NombreZapato, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c.ImagenZapato) }).OrderBy(s => s.NombreZapato).ToList();
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo real, que resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: Necesito obtener un string de esto Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c.ImagenZapato), estoy guardando en mi bd el nombre de la imagen como image, ocupo obtener el nombre de la imagen

Comment: El problema es que no puedes obtener el nombre de una imagen si esta fue guardada como un arreglo de bytes en la bd, para obtener el nombre debiste guardar en un campo tipo string el nombre de la imagen en la bd

Comment: Eso estaba pensando realizar el cambio a string, solo quería saber si se podía realizar algún tipo de conversión para no realizar todo el cambio en la bd, de todos modos muchas gracias